# Using extrn prinf:near in MASM

Tags: masm, masm32

Hello have a MASM assembly question. In the code below:

What is- extrn printf:near

It is refering to prinf function being called externally but what does the :near signify?

---

```
    ; include C libraries
includelib      msvcrtd
includelib      oldnames
includelib      legacy_stdio_definitions.lib    ;for scanf, printf, ...

.data
    prompt  db "Enter a number: ", 0
    fmt     db "%i", 0
    input   sdword ?
    output  byte 'z' ; initialize to 'z' as default

.code
    extrn   printf:near
    extrn   scanf:near

public  main
main    proc
    
    push    offset prompt
    call    printf
    add     sp,4

    ; get input with scanf
    push    offset input
    push    offset fmt
    call    scanf
    add     sp, 8
    
    cmp     input, 0
    je      LOUTPUT
    jg      LPOS
    jng     LNEG

LPOS:
    mov output, 'p'
    jmp LOUTPUT

LNEG:
    mov output, 'n'
    jmp LOUTPUT

LOUTPUT:
    push offset output
    call printf
    add  sp, 4

    ret
main    endp

end
```

Comment: In 16-bit real-mode code, addresses that are in the same 64k segment are called "near", and addresses that are in a different segment are called "far".  So, `extrn printf:near` means that the `printf` function will be loaded in the same 64k segment as our code, so we don't have to use a full 16:16 address to call it.  The C runtime library was delivered in "near" and "far" variants.  As an aside, Windows can no longer run 16-bit code like this.

Comment: I don't see anything that would make this code 16-bit. Granted, OP has not shown us their `.model` directive. In a `flat` memory model, `near` would be the default distance, so specifying it explicitly is redudant.